# Get email address from correspondent cell formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I what to make a list with emails and when I put in cell A2 a name, in cell B2 should appear the address for that particular person. If the name is not in the list, cell B2 should have value 0 . With VLOOKUP it will return N/A if the name is not in the list.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
=iferror(vlookup(a1, e:f, 2, false), 0)
```

The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) catches the non-match and provides a default value.